# Default volume too high for headphones

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, macbook-pro, audio

Is there a way to change the **default** volume setting for headphones/line out, i.e. the one you get after plugging a jack in *for the first time* since you've turned your Mac on and started OSX?

I'm using a 2008 unibody (aluminum) Macbook, running Snow Leopard. And several times I've run the risk of hurting my ears because of that default value (half of the scale).

Comment: my ear hurts. stupid mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [breakaway](http://mutablecode.com/apps/breakaway). You can write a quick applescript to change the volume back and forth when when the headphone is connected/disconnected, and much more

Comment: thank you very much, this _would_ be a solution, if it weren't for the bug that doesn't let me enable any trigger in the AppleScript plugin... I'm reporting it, hopefully it will be solved soon.

Comment: kinda works: I can't really get the AppleScript plugin to work, but since I installed Breakaway the headphones volume is remembered across reboots... I don't really understand, but I'm accepting the answer anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  Setting the volume as low as it could go was still too loud.

Here's a solution that worked for me:

1. Download [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/)
2. Set it up so that you have the following:
3. Sources: Pass-Thru
4. Output Channels: Channels 1&2
5. Monitors: [Select your headphone device]

Now all audio is routed to a virtual device, which outputs to your headphones.  This gives you an additional volume slider for more fine grained control, which will allow you to set your headphones to be much quieter than you could normally with the default OSX volume options.

Answer (score 1):

Open "AppleScript Editor"

Add this line:

> set volume 1.5

Then File > Save As

In the file format box choose "Application" and check the "Run Only" box. Name the file and save it somewhere you can find it.

Then if you drag that app into your dock, you can right click it, select Options > Open at Login.

This will set the volume to around 3 boxes of the scale on startup. However it will not detect if you have headphones plugged in or not. It will just always set the volume lower.

Comment: If you don't have headphones plugged in, then plugging them will change volume back to default "half of the bars" :-(

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I agree with @Peter: I don't think this really solves my problem.

Comment: That's strange. It should be remembering the volume levels. You might need a PRAM reset (this manages remembering volume levels I believe)

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379

Comment: @maclema: The thing is, my computer _does_ remember its "basic" volume setting, but not the one for headphones (not across reboots, at least). Do you think that's also managed by PRAM? In other words, does your Mac behave differently? I thought it was a "by design" thing, and asked here looking for some workaround.

Comment: By the way, whenever I plug in headphones **before** booting my Mac, the issue does not apply and I get the same "decent" volume I set the time before.

Comment: All the volume levels should be remembered by the PRAM. When I reboot my macbook pro both volume settings are remembered correctly.

Comment: @maclema: So that's just an issue of mine (and of Peter's). Weird. I wonder if it has to do with the specific Macbook model…

Answer (score 1):

Check these values each time before you plug in your headphones.

[image: System Preferences for Sound]

Check the box for "Show volume in menu bar." Each time before you plug in any headphones, go to your Menu bar and manually lower the volume.

[image]

Trying to solve this problem with AppleScript and the like is severly over-engineering a solution.

Comment: … thanks, but that doesn't answer my question. I definitely know how to adjust the volume manually, but I wish I wasn't forced to do that _each time_ I use headphones; I still forget sometimes.

Comment: Also, lowering the volume _before_ plugging in headphones, as you suggest, does not work: as I wrote in the question, the first time I plug them in after starting my Mac, the volume is automatically reset to half scale, no matter what the volume was before the insertion.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem with a Mac Pro (late 2009) under Snow Leopard, and it would NOT remember volume settings under any circumstances. I remember seeing online that several other users of this same model Mac Pro had exactly the same problem. So I'm sorry I can't provide a definitive fix. Please file a bug report with Apple!